# Is there a way I can "tag" adjacent elements in a numpy array with the same element?

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I'm using python 2.7 and I randomly generate areas in OpenCV that at the end look like this in a numpy array:

```
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

I actually work with bigger matrices and can generate up to 5 areas. 
What I want to do is to read the generated matrix and "group" areas to generate a second matrix that looks like this:

```
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 2 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 2 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 2 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

So if at the end I have a matrix with 5 numbered spots.
I'm pretty new to python but somehow I think that may be an easy a fast way of doing this. I hope someone can help me.

Comment: Sorry this is not a free code writing service, you are expected to show your effort and code. That said I don't think there is an 'easy' way to solve this ('easy' being totally subjective) but I'd suggest you to look into deep-first-search or breadth-first-search to identify your groups 1 by 1... This can also be solved using graph theory, identifying the connected components of your graph.

Comment: @Julien Bernu I may be wrong here, but it seems like he is asking for a direction rather than for free code. Do you really have to show your effort at reinventing the wheel, even if you suspect (and rightly so) it is already invented?

Comment: @Headcrab yeah this is a fine line... Overlooking the fact I didn't know that this 'wheel' already existed indeed, one could argue that you have to show at least a bit of effort no matter what: either effort at trying to invent the wheel, or effort at looking out there if someone already invented it.

Answer (score 4):

[`scipy.ndimage.label`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.label.html#scipy.ndimage.label) in SciPy does exactly that

You need to define a structure which evaluates which elements belong to a group, for example:

```
structure = [[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]
```

if you want to find elements that are in the neighbourhood including diagonals, or

```
structure = [[0,1,0],[1,1,1],[0,1,0]]
```

if you only need the ones left/right/top/bottom of one point. Note that the function returns two values, the first is your requested array and the second is the number of found "labels".

You might find some of the other functions in [`scipy.ndimage.measurements`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/ndimage.html#measurements) useful in this context.